# Javascript Regex everything before a space and including the space

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove all text before a space and the space itself from a list of strings. For example, `John Doe` needs to be just `Doe`. How could I do that?

Comment: Maybe .Split() ?

Comment: Show some code, be more specific: Just two words, or 2+ words? If 2+ words, last word only, or skip first word only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern would work, but it would only work for first space

`[^\s]*\s`

Usage : `str.replace(/[^\s]*\s/,"")`

If you want to support something like `"John    Doe"`
Then this pattern would work `[^\s]*\s+`

```js
console.log("John Doe".replace(/[^\s]*\s/,"")) //only one first space
console.log("John        Doe".replace(/[^\s]*\s+/,"")) //many spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be regex? As an option; if you need everything after the space, you can just use `split` and then `pop` to get the last item.

```
var str = 'John Doe';
var final = str.split(' ').pop();
console.log(final);
```

Here is a solution using a list of string, as you mentioned:

```js
var strList = ['John Doe', 'Jane Smith', 'Stack Overflow'];

for (var i = 0; i < strList.length; i++)
{
  var final = strList[i].split(' ').pop();
  console.log(final);
}
```